# Bulk insert into SQL Server with vba

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert a lot of values into SQL Server in one SQL insert statement. using a call of Proc Stock with my VBA code 
for example :

```
[... definitions of variables ...]
     If Not dico Is Nothing Then
        For Each current_id In dico.Keys
            Set prm = .CreateParameter(CStr(current_id), adVarChar, adParamInput, str_length, current_value)
            .Parameters.Append prm
        Next current_id
```

this code works perfectly when i have a single dictionary
but how about when i have an array of dictionaries , can prm contains a list of values (all values in a dico) instead of one value (.Parameters become a list of lists)? there is other methode to do that?

Thank you ,

Comment: can't you just add another Loop, which Loops through your dicts and names the active one dico every time?

Comment: that will be a way to do it , but i dont find it optimal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246117/inserting-multiple-values-into-a-sql-database-from-excel-through-vba-script?rq=1 ?

Comment: Thank you for your response but that's not what i'm looking for, i wanna send a 2-dim data to my DataBase